Scalability of openmp
I have a piece of openmp code for testing scaling of mutithreads:
void  openmp_scalabity_test ()
{
  
    int tid ;
    
    omp_set_num_threads(numberofthreads);  // here I specify the number of threads: 
    double t0, t1;
    
    #pragma omp parallel private(tid, t0, t1)
    {
      
        t0 = MPI_Wtime();

        #pragma omp for
        for(std::size_t zindex=0; zindex<10000000000; zindex++)     
        {
                 
                    tid = omp_get_thread_num();

         }      
  
        t1 = MPI_Wtime(); 

        #pragma omp barrier 
        if(tid==0)
        {
            std::cout <<" Multithread wall clock: "<<t1-t0<<" in threads: " << omp_get_thread_num()<<std::endl;
        }
        
    }
}


I run the code by mpi,
mpirun --bind-to none -np 1 ./test

My CPU info as follows:
rchitecture:             x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):         32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:          46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:             Little Endian
CPU(s):                   24
  On-line CPU(s) list:    0-23
Vendor ID:                GenuineIntel
  Model name:             12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12900K
    CPU family:           6
    Model:                151
    Thread(s) per core:   2
    Core(s) per socket:   16
    Socket(s):            1
    Stepping:             2
    CPU(s) scaling MHz:   17%
    CPU max MHz:          5200.0000
    CPU min MHz:          800.0000
    BogoMIPS:             6374.40

Here is bit confusing for me.  It seems I have 16 cores, and each core has 2 threads. I expect that I can get good scaling up to 32 threads.
However, here is the time for the test:
1 threads:  3.93
2 threads:  2.01
4 threads:  1.04
8 threads:  0.56
16 threads: 0.58
32 threads: 0.63

It seems I can only get good scaling up to 8 threads.

see https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/134599/intel-core-i912900k-processor-30m-cache-up-to-5-20-ghz/specifications.html
you have 8 performance cores (with 2 threads per core) and 8 efficient cores (with one thread per core) which sums to 24 threads as reported in the CPU info. So scalability is limited to 16 threads and only if you make sure to only use the performance cores.

I did not notice the difference between P-cores and E-cores. Thanks.  How can I make sure I am using only the performance cores in order to see the scaling up to 16 threads? Is there any way to select them in the code? Or is the scaling up to 8 threads  norm/acceptable for this kind of cpu?

you can use lstopo from the hwloc package (the performance cores have two threads) and then bind your appli. iirc lstopo return the logical core numbers that can be used with hwloc-bind. but if you plan to bind your app with taskset or numactl, you will need to use the physical core numbers (depending on your bios, they will be the same or different)

You cannot do that in the code and even if you could it would be a very bad idea for portability (it would only work on your CPU). Thread binding is indeed the key for that, but not only. Big-little CPU are barely supported by HPC tools and actually many parallel runtimes. It is not surprising since such processor are AFAIK not used on HPC servers and rather new too (in production). They tend to cause threads not to operate at the same speed which needs to be addressed.

This means classical fork-join loops with a static scheduling should not be used on such CPU. Indead, dynamic/guided scheduling should be used on such machine and barrier and fork-join loops should be avoided as much as possible (same on many cores CPUs). Tasks can often help. The bad news is that task and more dynamic scheduling (and tasks) also causes issues on some others CPUs where the static scheduling is far much faster (e.g. AC-922). Using a user-defined (runtime) scheduling is a good solution to mitigate this problem though this is far from being great.

An alternative solution is to support such special architectures at the MPI level : you can divide the work in 2 groups : 1 for big cores and 1 for little cores. But then each needs to use a different number of threads which make things complicated. Since there is generally 2 times more little cores than big one on Intel CPU, you can split the work in 3 groups : 1 with possibly more work than the 2 others. This is not easy to do for large/complex applications though...

A last alternative is not to care about this problem and assume 1 big core = 2 little core and use twice more threads on big ones. Or to use the same number of thread if big cores are not so good on your application (their speed is dependent of the exact code being executed since it is not the same micro-architecture). This is the solution using a manual thread binding. Note that the scalability is dependent of the kind of core used (not the same for little and big cores), and also the exact instructions executed so your benchmark is certainly not representative of real-world applications.

As a result, you may not observe any speed up between 1 and 2 threads on 1 big core regarding the specific target code due to SMT (2 hardware threads -- a.k.a. logical cores -- running on the same physical core). The same thing applies when some threads are scheduled on little core while others are on big ones.

I would say that on such a CPU, scalability is limited to 8 threads, and assuming that each thread runs on a different big physical core. Logical cores rarely help in HPC applications. Also, scalability is entirely dependent on the code: some codes scale well, some other codes don't.

Thank you all for these useful inputs.

@PierU Here it can be useful since the OP use a big-little CPU. Codes can typically be 1.5 faster with 8 big cores + 8 little cores (assuming they are used efficiently which this is hard to do) compared to just using 8 big cores. Indeed, 1 big core is approximately equivalent to 2 little cores in term of computational power. This is why Intel decided to use SMT-2 on big cores. See benchmarks here confirming this.

@PierU Besides, on newer CPU, Intel started to add more efficient cores since big-cores are only better for applications that does not scale well. For large scale applications, efficient core are better (they are much smaller, consume less power, execute code more efficiently internally due to less wasted transistors for most applications). This trend has been predicted and expected to continue (since most applications do not scale and we do not have any other way to make them faster without huge dev costs). AMD started to do the same with Zen4c though it is still mostly the same µ-arch.
